# How to add a paragraph between two input fields of form in elementor Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[form elementor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6WLF.png)

I want to add a paragraph about the above input field in the form but I cannot figure out how to do it, help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using native Elementor Pro block, you can add text or any content between your input fields by adding field named "HTML".